# PWM on phototransistor

Tags: led, pwm, infrared, phototransistor

I am pulsing the VDD with 50% duty cycle at a frequency of 188 Hz (PWM).
I get some weird spikes on my output TP3. Am I missing something about phototransistors?

Here is the picture of the IR circuit and the output from TP3:
[image]

Here is the circuit of the PWM output and how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60018/discussion-on-question-by-user2634037-pwm-on-phototransistor).

Comment: Did you oulsing vdd of photo tr. too?

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing the same kind of "peaking" circuitry used to pulse LEDs very fast. For example, you place a capacitor in parallel with R3 and the result should be that every time you switch on, the LED gets overdriven with more current than what it will settle out to which makes it initially brighter as well as turn on faster.

There are similar methods that do the reverse when turning the LED off by forcing a momentary reverse voltage so-called "carrier sweep" to sweep carriers out of the LED depletion region. This forces the LED to turn off faster too but it does not look like that is an issue in your circuit. This can be accomplished using the kick of an inductor or the discharge of a capacitor.

You have to be cautious with all these methods though so you don't burn out your LED. I'm not very familiar with such circuits and have not needed to use one yet but if you search terms like "LED" or "laser diode" combined with "carrier sweep" you come up with example circuits. Not many though, and most are buried in research papers.

Here is one example:

[image]

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6851184/

Comment: LEDs are extremely fast and don't need this type of peaking.

Comment: @jp314 Obviously not all LEDs for all applications since these methods exist for LEDs.

Comment: The LED itself doesn't need this. It is possible that the driver and wiring do have parasitic capacitance, and the peaking can mitigate this. The OP is running in the kHz range and it is extremely unlikely to be needed.

Comment: @jp314 Oh yeah. He's running hella slow. But whatever the cause, the extra umph of a brighter LED could help overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that its not a spike, and because it is a photo transistor. The transistor is slow, after a spike, the photo transistor lowers the voltage/current. It is recommended to use a laser, just use a mosfet. Then connect it to a laser, and on the output, just put an led, right into a common transistor, (you might need an op amp to amplify the led signal)